# How to clean deleted process of mysql?

Tags: mysql, memory, process, root

My /root using 96% of the memory and i am not able to find for what its using. When i tried "lsof / | grep deleted" i got this result . Is this the cause of using this much memory .

Please help me out on this .

```
[~]# lsof / | grep deleted
mysqld      3541     mysql    4u   REG    8,1        0  527413 /tmp/ibIWmwSO (deleted)
mysqld      3541     mysql    5u   REG    8,1      554  529198 /tmp/ib7EytVp (deleted)
mysqld      3541     mysql    6u   REG    8,1        0  529199 /tmp/ib6h2qY0 (deleted)
mysqld      3541     mysql    7u   REG    8,1        0  529202 /tmp/ib2Kh01p (deleted)
mysqld      3541     mysql   17u   REG    8,1        0  529813 /tmp/ibTadvzA (deleted)
```

Comment: Have you tried turning it off and on again? Not kidding, but all those results are stored in `/tmp`, so a reboot would probably clean them. Also, try running `find / -xdev -type f -size +100M` to see which files are the largest in `/`

Comment: 1.: This output only tells us that mysqld process with PID 3541 still has access to 5 temporary files - which are not referenced in the filesystem anymore - with an overall filesize of 554 Bytes. 2.: `lsof` might be the wrong tool for disk utilization infos or is there any unmentioned reason for using `lsof` instead of f.e. `du`? 3.: Check out [tracking disk utilization](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/125429/219604) or [similar Questions](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/314394/219604) on how to find files of certain size and/or how to analyze disk usage.